# "Once There was a Boy" vs "Once upon a time, there was a Boy"

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I thought "Once upon a time, there was a Boy" is quite a "standard" way to write an opening line of a story. But then I saw this book called "[Once There was a Boy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0399171096)". It sounds quite unnatural compared to "Once Upon a time, there was a Boy". Is this a grammatically correct phrase?

If not, is it because it is used as a (children's) book title so it is okay that the grammar doesn't need to be 100% correct?

Comment: ["**Once there was a way** to get back homewards“](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcQjM7gV6mI) The opening line of a beautiful Beatles' song "Golden Slumbers”

Comment: Good point. I feel a bit embarrassed that it didn't come to my mine as I love Beatle songs

Comment: Or split the difference… "Once there was a time" ;) Songs by Tom Jones & Ten Years After, and a BBC documentary.

Comment: _Once upon a time_ is the classic way to start a fairytale-type story, but in any other kind it would be something of a cliché.  There's nothing unnatural about _Once there was a boy..._ or _There was once a boy..._

Comment: Don't write 'boy' with a capital B unless it is in a title.

Answer (score 2):

The book's title “Once there was a boy…” is perfectly grammatical, it suggests that there was a boy who lived a long time ago.

There are other examples of this usage:

> **Once there was a fire**; and Miss Turner, the precise elder daughter, seeing them running, hoped it was not *their* house.
> *Hetty* by Henry Kingsley (1869)

> There are salmon in the lake, and pike, and otters, too. **Once there were wolves** in these parts and wild boars—folks used to make pits for them.
> *[Kirsten's Adventures](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Kirstin_s_adventures_by_the_author_of_Ca/PLwBAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Once%20there%20were%20wolves%20in%20these%20parts%22&pg=PA84&printsec=frontcover)* (1871)

***[ONCE THERE WERE WOLVES](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/443964/once-there-were-wolves-by-mcconaghy-charlotte/9781784744397)*** (2021) is also the title of a recent New York Times bestseller

> **Once, there was a way**
> To get back homeward
> Once, there was a way
> To get back home.

The opening line of a Beatles' song entitled *[Golden Slumbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcQjM7gV6mI)* (1969) A nostalgic ballad where the singer comes to accept that the path home no longer exists.

Comment: What about "Once upon a time"? How is it different, or is it the same?

Comment: It is a set expression, traditionally used for children's tales. If you use it, that is what most readers are going to think of.

Comment: @gotube   I answered whether the title (Once there was a boy…) was grammatical. It is and I supported it with evidence.

Comment: @ColinFine when you said "It is a set expression", were you referring to "once there was a boy" or "once upon a time, there was a boy" ? I am confused.

Comment: Is "to get back homeward" grammatical?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗: I meant that "Once upon a time" is a set expression.